# Possibly-Unicode symbols on a pixelated background

Tags: cipher, steganography

I decoded an MP3 by exporting it to photoshop and found the following image. Could it be Unicode? If so how do I go about decoding it? The answer to this will uncover another step in a long puzzle I'm a part of.

[image]

Source: CryptoZoo Discord group

Comment: Where is this from? All questions using puzzles from another source must be properly attributed.

Comment: Apologies. Its from a riddle group within the CryptoZoo discord, find it in the riddle channel if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like

> oddly written "hide".

Comment: Could also be "hive"